# How to use `eval` in typed racket?

Tags: typed-racket

I evaluated an expression in the form of `(time (eval ......))` in the repl (with `-I typed/racket` on the startup), and there occurred an error:

```
string:1:0: Type Checker: Polymorphic function `time-apply' could not be applied to arguments:
Domains: (-> a ... a b) (List a ... a) 
         (-> b) Null 
Arguments: (-> AnyValues) Null
  in: (time (eval ......))
 [,bt for context]
```

How can I specify the number and type of `eval`'s results?

I've tried using `cast` and `assert`, which produced new errors.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with the exceedingly unusual type of 'eval'.

Two possible fixes:

```
#lang typed/racket

(time (call-with-values (λ () (eval (+ 3 4))) (inst list Any)))
```

or, if you don't need to capture the result, you can do something much simpler like

```
#lang typed/racket

(time (begin (eval (+ 3 4)) #f))
```